# Syncing from genesis instead of snapshot

Tags: cardano-db-sync, cardano-graphql

I start the docker as followed in the guide:

```
export NETWORK=mainnet &&\
docker pull inputoutput/cardano-graphql:6.2.0-${NETWORK} &&\
docker pull inputoutput/cardano-graphql-hasura:6.2.0 &&\
docker pull cardanosolutions/cardano-node-ogmios:v5.1.0-${NETWORK} &&\
RESTORE_SNAPSHOT=https://update-cardano-mainnet.iohk.io/cardano-db-sync/13/db-sync-snapshot-schema-13-block-7519843-x86_64.tgz \
docker-compose up -d &&\
docker-compose logs -f
```

However, db-sync didn't start from a point where I passed as a RESTORE_SNAPSHOT parameter instead started at 0 to sync from genesis which takes too much time to get sync. Any recommendations? If I keep waiting to make it sync via genesis probably will last 2-3 weeks.

Comment: Rolling back to genesis like this can be due to 3 reasons: the node is not synced, the node and db-sync are running on different networks or wrong/missing ledger state directory.

Comment: What you mean by node is not Ogmios right? I mean my node and db-sync are running on same computer in different screens and it's sync. However, I did not pass any parameter while starting db-sync about the ledger path.

Comment: On the `db-sync` command line there is a `--state-dir` parameter. That specifies the directory where the ledger state is expected.

Comment: If the state directory is empty then it will roll back to genesis.

Comment: One common issue when using snapshots is that the ledger state part of the snapshot is restored to one place and `db-sync` expects it in another.

Comment: Do you mind sending the link where I pass the parameter while starting db-sync? I did follow the guide and I don't know how to pass --state-dir parameter when running via docker compose.

Comment: Documentation is at https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/building-running.md . The `--state-dir` parameter should point to the directory where the `db-sync` should store its ledge state data (assuming you are syncing from genesis) or where `db-sync` will find the ledger state data from the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot will only be applied if cardano-node is synced past the snapshot point, since the benefit of using it would be eliminated given cardano-db-sync rolls back to genesis under these conditions. For best results, ensure the node is close to the network tip prior to upgrading.